# Which adverb implies supreme confidence, falling just shy of arrogance?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms, adverbs

> When he participated in debates and round table discussions, Christopher Hitchens spoke with supreme confidence.

I'd like to replace `with supreme confidence` with an adverb that implies supreme confidence, falling just shy of arrogance.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: IMO, just about any adverb will fail to convey the same message as _with supreme confidence_. There are words such as _certitude_ or even _chutzpah_ which might convey a similar sentiment, but alas, not as adverbs.

Comment: So you want something between *confidently* and *hubristically?* I'm not sure that English adverbs have enough fine gradations for that. You could say *very confidently* or *most confidently*.

Comment: +1 I think there might be a fine line between 'supreme confidence' and arrogance.

Comment: Why don't we just use *confidently*? Either you are confident or are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with:

- commandingly
- boldly
- brilliantly

Answer (score 5):

How about *[eloquence](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eloquence)*, *[aplomb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aplomb)*, or *[poise](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poise)*?

### eloquence

> 1: discourse marked by force and persuasiveness; also : the art or
> power of using such discourse
> 2: the quality of forceful or persuasive
> expressiveness

### aplomb

> : complete and confident composure or self-assurance

### poise

> a : easy self-possessed assurance of manner

---

> ...Christopher Hitchens spoke with (*eloquence*, *aplomb*, *poise*).
>
> ... Christopher Hitchens spoke with *marked (eloquence*, *aplomb*, *poise*).

Comment: None of these satisfy the OP's requirements. He'd "like to eliminate _with supreme confidence_".

Comment: @coleopterist okay, fine: *eloquently*.

Comment: I think "aplomb" works really well for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

- dauntlessly
- self-assuredly
- intrepidly
- determinedly
- purposefully
- drivingly
- decisively
- firmly
- assuredly
- enthusiastically
- aggressively
- fervently
- persistently
- unremittingly
- zealously
- ardently
- animatedly

But I like the prepositional phrase just fine, and don’t see any real need to replace it with a single-word adverb.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **imperiously**.

**Imperious** is defined as:

*a : befitting or characteristic of one of eminent rank or attainments : commanding, dominant*

A second meaning is:

*b : marked by arrogant assurance : domineering*

This word weems to be on the border of what OP is seeking.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the word ["positively"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/positively) justifies the definition quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go for *[audacity](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/audacity)*.

From Oxford Dictionaries Online:

> A willingness to take bold risks.

You can be commended for audacity, or a plan being audacious, but it can also be used negatively, as in the sheer *cheek* or *gall* of someone.

*Your audacity knows no bounds* is a fine example of a sentence that could be used in both the positive and negative senses, dependent on context of course. I appreciate this has already been answered but felt that *audacity* captures the negative element quite well!